# Story about constant westward travel with miles as currency and robot doctors and car salesmen

Tags: story-identification

Everyone is always traveling, all the time,  and always westward.  Doctors and car salesmen are robots.  Miles are currency.   I only read half the story and lost the site.  I don't know the title or author to look it up.

Comment: Was this a short story? A book? Fantasy? Sci-Fi? Online? On paper? If you go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, you'll get a list of things you can edit into your question.

Comment: Try http://reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue as well

Comment: Its a short story. Scifi. I was reading it online and I lost the site midway through.

Comment: Isn't it in your browsing history?

Comment: No. I was reading on my phone and it was a link through free speculative fiction. Free speculative fiction is all that shows in the history,  not the site the story was on